# Spring Validator: Could not autowire. No beans of 'Validator' type found

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, spring-validator

I don't know if I need to and some more code/details about this but I am ready to supply more info if needed :)

I get: `Could not autowire. No beans of 'Validator' type found`. There are similar questions in here but there are not about `Validator`. I tried to autowire it via constructor but it is still same. I use Intellij Ultime edition. Latest version of `spring-boot-starter-xxx-xxx` which is 1.4.1.RELEASE at the moment.

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
    }
}
```

Edit:

I changed my code to this and it worked. Thanks for answers..

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}


@Override
public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator());
    validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator());
}
```

By the way, I just wonder if the person who voted down this question can explain why he/she did that?

Comment: Plz give your configuration file as well

Comment: Hi @JekinKalariya. Sorry to asking but what do you mean by configuration? I don't use xml configurations just java annotations.

Comment: ok then give your validator class and where you component scan also your also  beans.xml

Comment: @JekinKalariya I use `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in application class. And my validator class is all you see in my question. I don't think this problem is code related. It looks like a bug. I think this problem is not  occurring on Intellij community edition.

Comment: `@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}`
this is what I needed :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring library just contains an interface for `Validator`. You need to add a dependency to your project that actually implements the Validation framework [`JSR-303`](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) like [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/).

Comment: `compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator"` - is this enough in case of gradle?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing code like above you can add `@Qualifier` annotation and injecting by the field like below:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultValidator")
private Validator validator;
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @rorschach Spring library have an interface. You require an implementation to use the validator. Now it may be a 3rd party implementation or a custom made user-defined implementation.
Here is the [LINK](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator) which shows the example of both Hibernate validator and a Custom validator.